# rsync sets wrong group

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have a bash script to sync a Zendframework site between two servers, but for some reason one file doesn't get the correct owner/group. Since the file then becomes unreadable by apache the site goes down on that server.

On the first server I have the following file:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 monit www-data 4184 2012-03-14 05:39 application.ini
```

This should be exactly the same on the second server since both the user monit and the group www-data exists there to, but this is not the case as seen below.

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 monit monit    4184 2012-03-14 05:39 application.ini
```

This file is the only one affected. All other files gets the correct permissions, owners and groups. The rsync command is as follows

```
rsync -az --delete --stats  --include="document_root/.*" --exclude=".*" SERVER1 SERVER2
```

rsync is version 3.0.3, Server 1 is a Ubuntu 9.04 and Server2 is Debian 5.0

At the moment the problem is circumvented by setting the permission on the original file to -rwxrwxr--. The synced file will still have the wrong group, but is at least readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that `monit` user is in `www-data` group on the target server.
Try rsyncing the problematic file only, while running rsync on the target server and add one or more -v options, then look at the output:

```
$ groups monit |grep www-data
$ rsync -avv source_host:path/to/application.ini ./application.ini
```

Comment: User monit is only a member of the monit group and the only member in the group www-data is the user www-data created by apache. This is true for both servers. Only syncing that file didn't give any useful info, but I did notice more files syncing with the monit:monit ownership efter some more searching

Comment: If rsync is run as monit user (i.e. non-root), it cannot change file group to the groups it does not belong. Try as monit user `chgrp www-data application.ini` and see it fails with "Operation not permitted" error. If rsync is run as  www-data user it cannot chown to monit. The solution is either add monit user to www-data group, or change permissions as you did, or run rsync as root (bad idea).

Comment: Doh. Sometimes I'm just plain stupid. However, the same problem still arises even after I've added user monit to group www-data. It seems that I don't have permission to change group even to a group I am a member of. But I'm content with just adding user www-data to group monit for now, which also solves the problem, but if you can give me any more input I would be glad.

Comment: After changing user's groups don't forget to re-login.